# Bootstrap Validation via Javascript

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap v3.2.0 (the newest one).

I've create a simple standard contact form with required fields.

After you click on submit and you didn't fill up all required fields, a message an error message appears over the textbox, eg. `"Please fill it up"`.

So I did not change anything, this message came after I set the field to required. I like it how it is.

But now I want create an ajax call after someone clicked on the submit button.

So I build up a function and caught it with a `onclick` event.

My problem now is that the ajax call will trigger even if no fields was field up (the required ones). Maybe I am using the wrong event handler.

Does anybody know how to do it without using another Bootstrap Validation external Javascript?

Comment: can you add sample code for our reference?

Answer (score 0):

You're question is nearly impossible to answer without any code to reference.

Here is a sample of using ajax to click on an area.

```
$("#area_to_click").click(function() {

    $.ajax({url: 'your_url'}).done(function(your_data_call) { your_function();
    });

});
```